# PHP Array Length always 5

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am querying MS SQL Server and storing the results in a json array, then passing the results to Javascript.  My issue is that based off if a variable isset the array length SHOULD be either 4 or 5 length.  However, the array is ALWAYS showing a length of 5.

This is the php that I am using.

```
<?php
    $sql = "Select ";
    if (isset($_GET['namepull'])) {
        $sql .= "name,";
    }
    $sql .= " address, city, state, zip from employeefile";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $db->loadRowList();
    $output = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        array_push($output, $row);
    }
    echo $sql;
    $jsondata = json_encode($output[0]); 
?>
```

Which to me the below query strings should show an array length of 
4 = `Select address, city, state, zip from employeefile`
5 = `Select name, address, city, state, zip from employeefile`

Now the issue that I have is when it hits the below `<script>` a length of 5 is always produced, regardless of the query.  How should I modify the `<script>` so that an accurate count is returned?

```
<script>
    var arrayfromphp = <?php echo $jsondata;  ?>;
    alert (arrayfromphp.length);
</script>
```

If I perform a `console.log(arrayfromphp)` the last element when the count should be 4 is always `undefined x 1`

**Edit**
If I use `var_dump` below is the output I get (which is what I expect)

```
Array ( [0] => XXXXXXXXX [1] => New York [2] => New York [3] => 33333 )
Array ( [0] => Jackie [1] => XXXXXXXXX [2] => New York [3] => New York [4] => 33333 )
```

**Edit Again**
It appears the issue is stemming from how I am populating a Javascript array from the php array.  See edit below with notes above lines

```
var arrayfromphp = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;
//Shows accurate count of 4
console.log(arrayfromphp);

var values = [];
if (arrayfromphp.length = 5) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arrayfromphp.length; i++) {
        values.push(arrayfromphp[i]);
    }
} else if (arrayfromphp.length = 4) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayfromphp.length; i++) {
        values.push(arrayfromphp[i]);
    }
}
//Shows 5
alert(arrayfromphp.length);
//Shows 5 with undefined x 1
console.log(arrayfromphp);
```

Comment: have you var_dumped your results array to see what's actually inside? You might suprise yourself with the results

Comment: this `$sql .= " name,"` extra space is gonna cause issues

Comment: @clearshot66 - removed the extra space and still have 5 always returned.

Comment: @James - my mistake copy/paste error.

Comment: have you displayed value of `$_GET['namepull']`? is there a chance it is always set?

Comment: @Kaddath - I have echo $_GET['namepull'] onscreen and it will not display if it is empty.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - yes, I have used console.log to view the array elements, and when the count should only be 4, the last element is undefined x 1

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh that means the last element has found something that mathches the condition but doesn't have the property to echo out

Comment: And you have also checked what `$output[0]` contains on the server side, before you encode it as JSON? (Why only `$output[0]` anyway, why is this not the complete array that you have filled inside the loop?)

Comment: Where are you executing the query contained in `$sql`?  I only see the string being constructed.

Comment: @James - I originally omited that, I just edited post to include.

Comment: @CBroe - if I echo $output[0] I only get Array displayed on screen?

Comment: @clearshot66 Why would that cause issues?

Comment: That’s because you don’t use echo to output arrays ... use var_dump (preferably) or print_r.

Comment: It looks like you're using JDatabase, and in the docs I don't see any example of being able to jam a string into setQuery, rather a specially constructed query object.

Comment: @RiggsFolly because as it stood, he has a space after "Select ", in the query it would end up being `Select  name,`  extra spaces cause issues in SQL, not necessarily causing an error with the user's current issue though.

Comment: can it be the function `loadRowList()` that could "normalize" the list so that each row has the same number of elements?

Comment: @clearshot66 No, its quite legal to write `SELECT.......x....,....y....,....z` where the dots are for spaces, because spaces get removed in a comment

Comment: @CBroe - see my edit - I added the output of var_dump which is what I expect.

Comment: @James - I am using JDatabase.  I have used this same query structure in multiple places of syntax and everything executes exactly as I expect, with the exception of this one.

Comment: And finally ... what does the generated HTML code look like, what does that line `var arrayfromphp = ...` finally contain?

Comment: @CBroe - it appears my issue is from converting the php array to a javascript array.  See my most recent edit.

Comment: just replace `arrayfromphp.length = 5` by `arrayfromphp.length == 5`! Note: this is why i started to use the inverse syntax, that throws an error if assign is used instead of equals: `if(5 == arrayfromphp.length)`

Comment: @Kaddath - that solved it.  And thank you for the enlightenment about using the inverse.  I did not know you could use if(5 == arrayfromphp.length)

Comment: i also learned something by the way, didn't know that length property was editable.. js is weird sometimes!